# How To Load Fonts In Django

Tags: css, django

I have a project I am working on in django and i am trying to load locally installed fonts with the .tff extensions but they dont seem to be working. My css code is

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JandaAppleCobbler';
    src: url('../fonts/JandaAppleCobbler.tff') format("truetype"), local('JandaAppleCobbler');

}
```

My directory structure is

```
--static
  |--css
  |  |--main.css
  |
  |--fonts
    |--JandaAppleCobbler.tff
```

Comment: Your font extension `.tff` seems to be mistyped. It should be `.ttf` as for "True Type Font".

Comment: I am so ashamed. Lol please forgive the oversight.